# Problemas en select con MySQL en C#

Tags: mysql, c#, asp.net

tengo el siguiente problema:
Resulta que debo hacer una consulta de acuerdo a un usuario seleccionado desde un DataTable, y devolver todas las acciones realizadas por este usuario para cargar otro dataTable y mostrar la información en un GridView. El usuario pasa por parámetros y todo correcto, el problema es que únicamente me devuelve un valor y se carga solamente una fila, mientras que con la misma consulta que se realiza en C#, en Workbench sí devuelve los más de 400 acciones que ha realizado el usuario. He intentado de todo pero sigue devolviendo solo una fila de ese select que realizo. Este es el código:

```
          try
            {
                string Cadena = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ACCESO"].ConnectionString;
                DA.Conexion Con = new DA.Conexion(Cadena);
                DataTable Tabla = Con.ejecutarConsultaSQLTabla("SELECT Usuario,Nombre,Accion,TagID, str_to_date(concat(Fecha , '' , hora), '%d/%m/%Y%H:%i:%s') AS Fecha FROM Registro where Usuario = "+usuario+" order by Fecha");

                if (Con.IsError)
                {
                    Con.Destruir();
                    throw new System.InvalidOperationException(Con.ErrorDescripcion);
                }
                else
                {
                    Con.Destruir();
                    return Tabla;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                isError = true;
                errorDescripcion = ex.Message;
                return null;
            }
```

Cabe mencionar que he utilizado incluso en CommandType para pasar el parámetro usuario y también he intentado pasarlo directamente, pero eso no realiza ninguna diferencia, sigue devolviendo únicamente 1 fila

El código de ejecutarConsultaSQLTabla es el siguiente:

```
public DataTable ejecutarConsultaSQLTabla(String pSql)
        {
            MySqlCommand   cmd;
            MySqlDataReader   dr = null;
            DataTable Tabla = new DataTable();

            cmd = new MySqlCommand(pSql, conexion);

            // capturar la excepción
            try
            {
                IsError = false;
                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            }

            catch (MySqlException errorSql)
            {
                IsError = true;
                ErrorDescripcion = "Error en ejecutarSQL \n";
                ErrorDescripcion += errorSql.Message;
            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                IsError = true;
                ErrorDescripcion = "Error en ejecutarConsultaSQL \n";
                ErrorDescripcion += error.Message;
            }
            if (dr == null) return Tabla;
            Tabla.Load(dr, LoadOption.OverwriteChanges);
            return Tabla;
        }
```

Comment: Deberías examinar el método Con.ejecutarConsultaSQLTabla, parece ser el culpable

Comment: Seria bueno si puedes colocar el codigo de ejecutarConsultaSQLTabla (que esta dentro de DA.Conexion). Asi vemos exactamente cual es el command que ejecuta

Comment: Listo, el código de ejecutarConsulta lo agregué más abajo de la publicación original